# How to check if object contains an item using Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am using karma and jasmine as my testing framework. This is my code:

```
it('add() should add x to the reply object', function() {
    spyOn(ctrl, 'addxReply');
    ctrl.reply = {};
    ctrl.reply.post = 'test post';
    ctrl.add();
    expect(ctrl.addxReply).toHaveBeenCalled();
    console.log(ctrl.reply);
    expect(ctrl.reply).toContain('x');
});
```

This is my ctrl.add():

```
self.add = function() {
    self.reply['x'] = self.posts[0].id;
    self.addxReply();
};
```

The problem is, when I run the code, this is what it returns:

```
LOG: Object{post: 'test post', x: undefined}
Chromium 48.0.2564 (Ubuntu 0.0.0) Controller: MainCtrl add() should add x to the reply object FAILED
    Expected Object({ post: 'test post', x: undefined }) to contain 'x'.
```

As you can see, my reply object does contain `x` but the line `expect(ctrl.reply).toContain('x');` is still failing. Any idea how I can properly verify that my object contains a `x`?

Comment: try `(ctrl.reply.x).toBe(null)` since it's an object

Comment: @maioman that returns an error saying undefined is not null. When I do `(ctrl.reply.x).toBe(undefined)` then that returns no error but it also returns no error if I do `(ctrl.reply.y).toBe(undefined)` which an issue because I want to be able to check that `ctrl.reply.x` actually exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bug in what you created vs what's expected. Notice this line:

```
self.reply['x'] = self.posts[0].id;
```

It expects `ctrl` to have a property "posts" that is an array which has an index `0` which has a property named `id`. **Every one of those conditions fails**

You instead defined a singular property (not an array) under ctrl's property `reply`:

```
ctrl.reply.post
```

You need to change your test code:

```
it('add() should add x to the reply object', function() {
    spyOn(ctrl, 'addxReply');
    ctrl.reply = {};

    //ctrl needs an array named "posts" with one index
    //containing an object with an "id" property
    ctrl.posts = [ { "id": 'test post' } ];

    ctrl.add();
    expect(ctrl.addxReply).toHaveBeenCalled();
    console.log(ctrl.reply);
    expect(ctrl.reply).toContain('x');
});
```

Comment: Thanks! By the way, `expect(ctrl.reply).toContain('x');` still failed but I just changed it to `expect(ctrl.reply.x).toBe('test post');` and it worked.